# I can't pass a URL built by concatenating strings and object property value into a Vue.js directive of a package and I have no idea why

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a page where I render a lot of images and because of that I was advised to look up and implement image lazy loading. After googling, I decided to use the vue-lazyload package - https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-lazyload, however, I hit a brick wall rather quickly. Right now I render my images like this:

```
<div v-for='card in filteredByAll'>
    <img :src='"../assets/cards/" + card.cardCode + ".webp"'>
</div>
```

Which works fine and dandy. As you can see, I just build my URL inside the src. Now if I want to use the vue-lazyload package, I have to remove the src and add a Vue.js directive v-lazy and put the URL inside of it like this:

```
<div v-for='card in filteredByAll'>
    <img v-lazy="">
</div>
```

The problem is that whenever I try this:

```
<div v-for='card in filteredByAll'>
    <img v-lazy='"../assets/cards/" + card.cardCode + ".webp"'>
</div>
```

The image doesn't render. Honestly I'm not even sure if I can build the URL inside the v-lazy but what is my other option? I tried using random image URLs I found on google and it worked fine so the package is working fine, so I think I'm likely making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: "doesn't render" or "doesn't even set a src"? Because those are different issues entirely, and make a huge difference in terms of where the solution will be.

Comment: Well the image tag exists, however, it doesn't display an image, is 1x1px and the src is set to this - src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"

Comment: I see a few examples of what to do over in https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-lazyload#usage but none of them match what you've written. What happens when you change your code to match the usage examples?

Comment: I tried 2 of the examples and they work fine. If I loop over an array of objects which have the URL in a property and set the v-lazy to that property, it works fine but the thing is, In my example, the object doesn't have a property that contains the URL, I have to build them myself.

Comment: What if you preprocess `filteredByAll`? On the JS side, do a `.map()` that yields an array of URLs? (e.g. ```const urls = filteredByAll.map(card => `../assets/cards/${card.cardCode}.webp`)``` and then using that as your array of urls)

Comment: Hmmm, that might work. I'll try it.

Comment: I bet the issue is that Webpack isn't processing the constructed URL... I believe `../assets` get's moved somewhere and paths modified as default. What if you call the images with an absolute path?

Comment: @BryceHowitson I'm slightly confused as how to call the images with an absolute path. The images are located in ProjectFolder->src->assets->cards so when I'm accessing them in my project I just use @/assets/cards/card.webp or ../assets/cards/card.webp.

Comment: anything inside the `src` directory is hard to use an absolute path since it all gets modified by Webpack. Here's Vue's static assets [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder). Assuming you add an `images` dir inside that you would access the contents with`/images/file.ext`